# RDLC Report - No Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I am trying to make a RDLC report to convert to PDF.

This is my code:

```
public ActionResult Reports(string ReportType)
{
 MyApplication_dbEntities Entities = new MyApplication_dbEntities ();

DataSet1 DataSet1 = new DataSet1();
DataTable ordersTable = DataSet1.Tables["Orders"];

LocalReport localreport = new LocalReport();
localreport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Report1.rdlc");

var entities_data = from c in Entities.Orders
                              select c.FirstName;

localreport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", DataSet1.Tables["Orders"]));

string reportType = ReportType;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string fileNameExtension;

if (reportType == "PDF")
{
fileNameExtension = "pdf";
}
else
{
fileNameExtension = "jpg";
}
string[] streams;
Warning[] warnings;
byte[] renderedByte;
renderedByte = localreport.Render(reportType, "", out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment:filename + reservaties_report." + fileNameExtension);
return File(renderedByte, fileNameExtension);
}
}
```

I can make an PDF report, but with no data.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thx!!

Comment: You never Fill your DataSet with data.

Comment: @Crowcoder 
Thx, but can you tell me how i can do this properly?
Maybe with a very simple example?

Comment: Since I don't know anything about your database or the report you would do just as well to Google how to Fill a DataSet. It is very straightforward. But since I see you are using Entity Framework you probably just want to use that for your data source. It's been a long time since I've used RDLC but I just thought I'd mention that you can't expect to new up a DataSet and  have it full of data just because you named a DataTable "Orders".